# Which CHALLAN to use for paying tax

Tags: income-tax, india

I am individual and while filing ITR it is showing me tax is payable. Now I landed on this page https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp. But I am confused which challan to choose?

EDIT:

Actually tax deducted at source by company was less than what is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you need to pay Income Tax for some additional income as your TDS was less.

The challan to use is CHALLAN NO./ITNS 280; Further you need to select

- **Tax Applicable**: (0021)INCOME-TAX (OTHER THAN COMPANIES)
- **Type Of Payment**: (300)SELF ASSESSMENT TAX